# What desktop environments feature a searchable "Start" menu/launcher?

Tags: software-recommendation, panel, appmenu, xfce-panel, lxpanel

Aside from Unity, [KDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65089/116961) and [Cinnamon](https://askubuntu.com/a/100202/116961), which of the [many desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) support incremental search among the start menu items, including not just applications, but recent documents?

That is, which DEs integrate semantic search systems like Synapse ([no longer maintained](http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/04/synapse-launcher-is-not-maintained.html)), [Kupfer](https://live.gnome.org/Kupfer) or [GNOME Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Do)?

LXDE and XFCE do not, for example, though in XFCE you could press Alt+F2 and click the down arrow to search among installed applications (recent documents aren't added to this menu).

(Ideally, this menu would be [activated when the Win/Super key was released, which seems almost impossible to achieve](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51452/windows-like-global-shortcuts-with-the-super-key-in-xubuntu), though Cinnamon does it)

Comment: I use Synapse.Its an app/software searches for everything in your system including your recent documents.you can get it in the Software center.

Comment: What do you mean by "incrementally searchable"?

Comment: @Flimm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Gnome Shell to me. Have a try: http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/

Answer (score 1):

Enlightenment 17 supports this feature through a module called "Run everything". It is not necessarily as intuitive as the others, but with a little "getting used to" it can be pretty useful and quick.

Comment: [Unity is indeed slow](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232621/why-is-unity-a-slow-desktop-environment). "[Run everything](http://www.bodhilinux.com/e17guide/e17guideEN/everything.html#How%20to%20Run%20Everything)" seems interesting. And it can search files and the web too.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Dash has nice search functions, and easy extendable via scopes and lenses.