# Ubuntu terribly slow, barely able to move mouse

Tags: 14.04

This is my first time trying Ubuntu. I burned a DVD with version 14.04 and installed it alongside Windows 7. The machine here is an AMD Athlon 2 at 3ghz and 64 bit with 2gb of ram. After booting Ubuntu it goest to the desktop screen the icons down the left hand side. After 1/2 minute the mouse pointer shows up but the pointer is almost frozen: if I move the mouse a bit the pointer on screen will move maybe 30 seconds later. I did get it over to one of the icons and clicked on it but nothing happened.

I have a new USB mouse by the way and it works fine on the Windows side. I have limited computer knowledge compared to most people on this site. Do I need more horse power to run this version? Just stumped as what to ask even.

Comment: I too find it can be slow. In part this can be due to graphics as Unity is a heavy DE. If you have a poor graphics card, or if you have a good card but didn't install proprietary drivers then it can be make it difficult to meet the graphics demands of Unity. Your storage device can also be a possible cause. For example if you run from a laptop 5400rmp hard drive you may notice some lag, but on a quality SSD you likely won't, and from a ramdrive you for sure wont. I suggest trying Lubuntu as it's got lower graphics requirements, and if applicable install proprietary graphics drivers.

Comment: Your hardware is more than sufficient to run 14.04 / Unity smoothly. You most likely just need to install an appropriate driver for your graphics card (which?).

Comment: Could be same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/232621/why-is-unity-a-slow-desktop-environment

Comment: Thank to all for the suggestions. I loaded Lubuntu and let the program install all the updates. I then checked for driver updates for the graphics/monitor on the windows side. Lubuntu seems to be working mostly with an occasional fail to boot or display goes to lines. Reboot and all is well ??

Comment: Almost forgot that I loaded the 32 bit version, the 64 bit won't work. I have windows 7 pro which is the 64 bit version and that's always worked fine. oh well fun to learn something new

Answer (score -1):

64-bit on only 2GB RAM?

I don't know much about systems, but don't you think 32-bit would be more reliable for that small of an amount of RAM?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if you use 64-bit or 32-bit with any amount of RAM.

Answer (score -2):

May I suggest installing XFCE4 as your GUI?

Upon booting into Ubuntu, click and hold Ctrl + Alt + F1 to go into terminal. Follow instructions to login. I am suggesting this method because your GUI is painfully slow.
Upon logging in, type 'sudo apt-get install xfce4' and click enter. Click 'Y' when prompted. When the operation is complete, type 'sudo restart lightdm' and the login screen should appear and you will be able to select XFCE as your default GUI. It's much faster.

If you get lost throughout this process and want to return to the GUI, just Ctrl + Alt + F7.

Comment: Why suggest another DE? This will not help the user. The issue may not be related to Unity/Gnome at all.

Comment: Or Unity-2D, or any other window manager that doesn't require 3D hardware acceleration.... the issue is not with Unity/Gnome, it's with what it requires to run